# Neo4j delete all nodes and relationships apart from UkPostcode

Tags: neo4j

I can delete people and their associated nodes and edges with this:

```js
    const neo4jSearchAndDestroy = await runQuery({
      query: `
      unwind $deletedIDs as accountId
      match (p:Person{ id: accountId })-[*..3]-(c) 
      detach delete p, c
      `,
      params: {
        deletedIDs: deletedIDs,
      },
    });
```

But I don't want to delete the 'Postcode' node that is joined to the 'Person' node like this: (Person)-[:PLACE]-(Postcode)

I have experimented with `WHERE NOT` for example:

```
match (p:Person{ id: '08377f57-6d27-4426-bbf6-517501a23074' })-[*..3]-(c) WHERE NOT (p)-[:PLACE]-() return *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
  unwind $deletedIDs as accountId
  match (p:Person{ id: accountId })-[*..3]-(c) 
  with p,c WHERE NOT c:Postcode
  detach delete p, c
```